# jQuery replaceCheckbox script

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a JS code allowing me to replace the checkboxes in my HTML code.

My problem is: all my checkboxes are replaced but my other JS code do not work. If I click on the label, it's ok but not on the replaced checkbox.

## My HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCB" id="test" class="property-custom-field" />
<label for="test">Test</label>
<input type="hidden" name="moods" id="moods">
```

## My JS:

```
<script>
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { jQuery(this).replaceCheckbox(); });

$("input.myCB").click(function() {
        alert('Test');
        var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
        var locationBtn = $('#moods');
        var locationBtnValue = $('#moods').val();

        if(locationBtnValue.toString().indexOf(clickedId) == -1) { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue + clickedId + ","); }
        else { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue.replace(clickedId + ',','')); }
});
</script>
```

## My function to replace checkboxes:

```
<script>
replaceCheckbox: function() {

    //// vars
    var selCont = this;

    //// WRAPS IT AROUND SELECT
    selCont.wrap('<div class="checkbox-replace"></div>');
    var mainCont = selCont.parent();

    //// IF IT'S CHECKED
    if(selCont.is(':checked')) { mainCont.addClass('checkbox-replace-checked'); }

    //// MAKES IT OVERLAY THE CONTAINER
    selCont.css({ display: 'none' });

    //// WHEN WE CLICK THE MAIN CONTAINER
    mainCont.click(function() {

        //// IF IT'S CHECKED
        if(jQuery(this).attr('class').indexOf('checked') != -1) {

            //// UNCHECKS IT
            jQuery(this).removeClass('checkbox-replace-checked');
            selCont.removeAttr('checked');

        } else {

            //// UNCHECKS IT
            jQuery(this).addClass('checkbox-replace-checked');
            selCont.attr('checked', 'checked');

        }

    });

}
</script>
```

Hope you ll help me.

Thanks.

Comment: creating a jsfiddle would help enormously

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DJqFV/2/ But this is not like into my website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-configure the event handler after calling replaceCheckbox.

This script:

```
    $("input.myCB").click(function() {
        alert('Test');
        var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
        var locationBtn = $('#moods');
        var locationBtnValue = $('#moods').val();

        if(locationBtnValue.toString().indexOf(clickedId) == -1) { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue + clickedId + ","); }
        else { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue.replace(clickedId + ',','')); }
    });
```

is setting an event handler on existing input.myCB. But if you replace those with your other script, the event handlers are not added to the new checkboxes, so you need to call this another time to set them again.

**EDIT:**

Now that I can see your fiddle, I posted a new answer, please refer to it.

Comment: If you create a fiddlejs for your code, I should be able to help.

Comment: I have it but it miss all the style. This is my first time with fiddlejs: jsfiddle.net/DJqFV/2. I try to make it one here.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have your fiddle, I can see the error.

This line here:

```
replaceCheckbox: function() {
   // BLA BLA BLA
};
```

It throws an error (take a look at your javascript console). You should do this:

```
$.fn.replaceCheckbox = function() {
   // BLA BLA BLA
};
```

Comment: It makes the same. If I click on the label it's ok, but it does not works if I click on the checkbox. Here a demo on my beta site: http://perside.ca/www/v3/beta/?lang=en

Comment: I updated the code on the fiddle ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/DJqFV/3/)) and now, there is no error on the js console anymore, and when i click on test, the alert shows up. So it seems to be working, doesn'it ?

Comment: Also, your code set the checkboxes display to none, so it's not possible to click on them. So, instead of this `$("input.myCB").click(function() {` you should do this : `$(".checkbox-replace").click(function() {` to apply the event on the newly created div.